# How to clone different rows of table with an unique event

Tags: javascript

Making an ordering app. There is a div with a table containing all products with for each the price and a button to select it. There is a second div which containing selected products. So, i clone the selected product to put it in the second div. It runs but i had to make an event for each products and i would like to create an unique function using button class name to do this.

I tried to create a for() with no results but i'm a js beginner and i'va issues with my syntax

HTML

```
<h1>CHOOSE</h1>

<table id="starters">
          <tr>
            <th>PRODUCT</th>
            <th>PRICE</th>
            <th>ADD TO CART</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cherry</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td><button id="s1" class="item_button"></button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Peach</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td><button id="s2" class="item_button"></button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Strawberry</td>
            <td>12</td>
            <td><button id="s3" class="item_button"></button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Banana</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td><button id="s4" class="item_button"></button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Apple</td>
            <td>7</td>
            <td><button id="s5" class="item_button"></button></td>
        </tr>          
</table>

<h1>YOUR CHOICE</h1>   

<table id="products_cart">

</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var s0ne = document.getElementById('s1');
var sTwo = document.getElementById('s2');
var sThree = document.getElementById('s3');
var sFour = document.getElementById('s4');
var sFive = document.getElementById('s5');
let boxes = document.getElementById("starters")
let basket = document.getElementById("products_cart")

s0ne.onclick = function() {
  let clone = boxes.getElementsByTagName("tr")[1].cloneNode(true);
  basket.appendChild(clone);
}

sTwo.onclick = function() {
  let clone = boxes.getElementsByTagName("tr")[2].cloneNode(true);
  basket.appendChild(clone);
}

sThree.onclick = function() {
  let clone = boxes.getElementsByTagName("tr")[3].cloneNode(true);
  basket.appendChild(clone);  
}

sFour.onclick = function() {
  let clone = boxes.getElementsByTagName("tr")[4].cloneNode(true);
  basket.appendChild(clone);  
}

sFive.onclick = function() {
  let clone = boxes.getElementsByTagName("tr")[5].cloneNode(true);
  basket.appendChild(clone);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you can use jQuery:

```js
let basket = document.getElementById("products_cart")

$('.item_button').on('click', function(e) {
 let target = $(e.currentTarget);
 let clone = target.parents('tr')[0].cloneNode(true);
 basket.appendChild(clone);
})
```

Using pure JS, you could do something like this:

```js
let basket = document.getElementById("products_cart")

let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.item_button');

for (button of buttons) {
 button.addEventListener('click', cloneLine);
}

function cloneLine(e) {
 let td = e.target.parentNode;
 let tr = td.parentNode;
 let clone = tr.cloneNode(true);
 basket.appendChild(clone);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this javascript code :

```
add = function(e)
      {
        choices = document.getElementById('products_cart');
        choices.innerHTML=choices.innerHTML+e.target.parentNode.parentNode.innerHTML;

      }
      products = document.querySelectorAll('.item_button');

      for(i=0;i<products.length;i++)
         products[i].addEventListener('click',add,false);
```